# How to interpret equation in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

How can I write the following equation in Pascal?

[image]

Does it equal to `pow(x, 2) / (pow(pow(16 - x*x, 1/2)), 3)` ?

Comment: Or... `(x*x) / pow(16 - x*x, 3/2)` since square root cubed is taking to the `3/2` power, and not sure why you squared `x` as `x*x` in one case, but `pow(x, 2)` in another. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention the dialect, so I'll assume something still in active use like Lazarus/FPC/Delphi

Squared has a separate function sqr(), as does square root, sqrt(). For other values math.power is used (add math to your uses clause).

So that makes sqr(x)/power(sqrt(16-sqr(x)),3);

As a rule of thumb, the simplest expression gives the best precision.